# How to organize a large number of file/directory path constants

Tags: c#, file, path, code-organization

I have a static class where I keep a large number of relative paths that are used in different places in my application. It looks like that:

```
static class FilePathConstants
{
    public const string FirstDirectory = "First";
    public const string FirstSecondDirectory = "First/Second";
    public const string FirstSecondThirdFileA = "First/Second/Third/FileA";
    public const string FirstSecondFourthFileB = "First/Second/Fourth/FileB";
    ... nearly 100 of similar members
}
```

All of them are relative to some parent directory, location of which I know only during the program run. I need to keep them all together because it allows me to easily control what files are used by my application and change their locations from time to time.

However even though they are organized in alphabetic order and its easy to find a certain path, I need to be able to change some of them depending on some setting. Lets say, there is a setting 'bool SettingA' and when I turn it on, I have to do modify some of the paths to use a different directory or a different file name.

The problem is that now I can't use constants, I have to rewrite my code to properties or methods so that I can change file paths at runtime. And here where my code becomes much bigger in size and the strict order now looks ugly. Is there a way I can group them, so that it will not confuse anybody who uses this code? I can't break them into a separate classes because it is difficult to remember in what class what constant you may keep. For now I'm grouping them by regions, but I have a bad feeling that keeping more than one hundred of properties in one class is wrong.

**Edit:**

All directories and files that I declare in `FilePathConstants` are used in a large number of places in application (each path can be used multiple times, taking into account the fact that there is more then one hundred of paths - this is a large number). I would like to keep the interface of this class the same or with minimum changes to other classes that use them.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use rowstructs

Comment: What do you mean by 'rowstructs'?

Comment: It's a semiclass, a class but much lighter and useful in this cases, where a class may be to 'heavy' for this usage, it's recommended to use rowstructs

Answer (score 1):

Use something like "index" file to store the directory paths and load it in runtime.

```
const string indexFilePath = @"C:\dirlist.txt";
IEnumerable<string> paths = File.ReadAllLines(indexFilePath);
```

**Update**

I would like to suggest using indirection - "mapper" class.
Here is how it should look like.

```
public enum FileSystemElement
{
    FirstDirectory,
    FirstSecondDirectory,
    FirstSecondThirdFileA,
    FirstSecondFourthFileB
}

public class FileSystemMapper
{
    private readonly string _rootDirectory;
    private readonly Dictionary<FileSystemElement, string> _fileElements;

    public FileSystemMapper(string rootDirectory, string fileName)
    {
        _rootDirectory = rootDirectory;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        _fileElements = lines.Select(ParsePair).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
    }

    public string GetPath(FileSystemElement element)
    {
        string relativePath;
        if (!_fileElements.TryGetValue(element, out relativePath))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not found");
        }

        string resultPath = Path.Combine(_rootDirectory, relativePath);
        return resultPath;
    }

    private static KeyValuePair<FileSystemElement, string> ParsePair(string line)
    {
        const string separator = "|";

        // File element alias | Path
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            throw new ArgumentException("Null or empty line", "line");                

        string[] components = line.Split(new[] { separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (components.Length != 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("Line has invalid format", "line");

        FileSystemElement element;
        bool parseResult = FileSystemElement.TryParse(components[0], out element);
        if (!parseResult)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid element name", "line");

        string path = components[1]; // for clarity
        return new KeyValuePair<FileSystemElement, string>(element, path);
    }
```

Client example:

```
        FileSystemMapper fileSystemMapper = new FileSystemMapper(@"C:\root", @"C:\dirs.txt");
        string firstDirectory = fileSystemMapper.GetPath(FileSystemElement.FirstDirectory);
        string secondDirectory = fileSystemMapper.GetPath(FileSystemElement.FirstSecondDirectory);
        string secondThirdFile = fileSystemMapper.GetPath(FileSystemElement.FirstSecondThirdFileA);
```

Index file format: `<Element name>|<Path><New Line>`

Example:

```
FirstDirectory|First
FirstSecondDirectory|First\Second
FirstSecondThirdFileA|First\Second\Third\FileA
FirstSecondFourthFileB|First\Second\Fourth\FileB
```

Comment: Lets say I use an index file. Then for each line I will have to create a method or property. It seems that I'm returning to where I was

Comment: No, `paths` variable contains all your directories, so you can enumerate through directories.

Comment: It means that each time I need to get a path, I have to enumerate a hundred of paths, and I don't have any guarantee that it contains my path at all

Comment: Could you please provide us with some more context information: how are the directory paths used in your program?

Answer (score 0):

can you not use your projects Properties.Settings? it's stored in the .config file so can be edited after deployment

or just dont make them const, then you can edit them at runtime bu they revert to the original setting on next run.

or dont make the calss static and create an instance each time you use it, then change whats needed and discard the instance when finished.

Comment: I don't use Properties.Settings. The problem is that I need to change them from constants to properties but it makes my code very large and ugly, I need to organize those paths somehow